Из кодировки cp1252 в latin1 C#
Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне преобразовать строку из cp1252 в кодировку latin1
Код, который я использовал:
byte[] byte2cp1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252").GetBytes(textBox2.Text);
string text2latin1 = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetString(byte2cp1252);

В результате у меня переводится в символы: ????????????
Подскажите, как действовать?

Какую именно строку? Если с русскими символами, то во-первых это 1251, а во-вторых в latin не будет этих русских символов. Или это именно западноевропейский язык в строке?

@CrazyElf, спасибо огромное, вместо 1252, написал 1251 и у меня все получилось. У меня база на latin1 кодировке, поэтому такие манипуляции необходимо производить. Еще раз спасибо

Ну и хорошо, что всё получилось. В иностранных примерах кода в интернете часто пишут кодировку 1252, но это потому что европейцы, нужно учитывать, что у нас другая кодировка )

Не надо издеваться над текстом.

Вместо windows-1252 необходимо написать windows-1251 при переводе русских символов
